# Spring integration: how to adjust all outgoing error messages

Tags: error-handling, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I need to adjust all error messages going back to the caller of my integration flows so that I do not leak information, no matter if they are thrown as exception or handled as asynchronous errors. I'd like to avoid defining a custom error channel on every message handler.
I have tried to attach a transformer to the default error channel without success:

```
@Bean
IntegrationFlow errorFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("errorChannel")
            .transform("{'status': 500, 'error': 'Internal Server Error'}")
            .get();
}
```

Is there a central point where I can transform all outgoing error messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your logic, it looks like you deal with REST - request/reply. So, you need to return a reply to request point. This is available via `replyChannel` header of the request message. Such an information you can access in a `MessagingException.failedMessage` property of the `payload` in the `ErrorMessage`.

Summarizing all of that your `.transform()` must expect `MessagingException` as a payload and produce output message with copying headers from that `failedMessage`. This way the message will be sent to the reply channel of the HTTP Inbound Gateway request message.